# play framework and requirejs development javascript code

Tags: javascript, scala, requirejs, playframework-2.2

I am using requirejs to build frontend on play 2.2 framework. play provides great development/stage code difference for this case. In devel mode I am working with browser based requirejs and in stage I am using precompiled with r.js version of the project. But one feature fails - is it possible to distinguish on javascript side is it development mode or not and remove part of code during compilation or something like:

```
#ifdef DEVELOPMENT
code in Development only
#endif
```

Comment: javascript code doesn't run on the server side... you can include different versions of your scripts during page generation, depending on the development mode, as a workaround.

Comment: r.js compilator runs on server side in stageing prcess and produces one javascript file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default `r.js` uses UglifyJS to optimize your modules. In `r.js`' configuration you can use the `uglify` option to send configuration options to UglifyJS. For instance,

```
uglify: {
    defines: {
        DEV: ['name', 'false']
    }
},
```

This would tell `uglifyjs` replace every instance of the symbol `DEV` with the name `false`. Then, parts like this:

```
if (DEV) {
    // ....
}
```

would be automatically removed by `uglifyjs` as being unreachable.

See [`uglifyjs`' documentation](https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS) for the details of how that works.

You might also want to look at [UglifyJS2](https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS2), because it perhaps does more than UglifyJS. You can tell `r.js` to use it by setting the `optimize` option to `uglify2`, and use the `uglify2` option to control what it does.

Answer (score 0):

UglifyJS2  from  sbt-rjs  1.0.7 already has some other usefull option:

```
uglify: {
     drop_console: true
}
```

```
uglify2: {
     compress: { drop_console: true }
}
```

it removes all console.log messages from minified script.